# ChildPanel in ParentPanel resizes its content automatically

Tags: java, swing, resize, jpanel

my current project involves having multiple JPanels in one. The problem I'm facing is: The contents of the ChildPanels are automatically being resized without me wanting this.
I don **not** use a layout manager, I just prefer resizing everything by myself.

Is there any way I can prevent the automatic resize?

Some exmaple code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("TestFrame");
    f.setVisible(false);
    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setLocation(100, 100);
    f.setSize(350, 350);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    ChildPanel cp1 = new ChildPanel(Color.red, 20, 20);
    ChildPanel cp2 = new ChildPanel(Color.blue, 120, 120);
    ParentPanel pp = new ParentPanel();
    pp.add(cp1);
    pp.add(cp2);
    f.getContentPane().add(pp);
    f.setVisible(true);

}

public static class ChildPanel extends JPanel {

    private Color col;

    public ChildPanel(Color col, int x, int y) {
        super();
        this.col = col;
        setSize(50, 50);
        setLocation(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(col);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    }

}

public static class ParentPanel extends JPanel {

    public ParentPanel() {
        super();
        setSize(200, 200);
        setLocation(50, 50);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Layout managers exist for a reason, if you "prefer" to do things manually, then you will have to solve problems like this all the time - not to mention what will happen if your code ever ends up on some poor unfortunates Mac or Linux PC.

Comment: My code isn't designed to work on Linux or Mac due to the fact that I also use JNI in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don not use a layout manager

Well, in fact you are. No layout manager is set for parent panel, so FlowLayout is used by default. To prevent this from happening you can change the code above as follows:

```
public ParentPanel() {
    super(null);
    setSize(200, 200);
    setLocation(50, 50);
}
```

Working without a layout manager is not recommended, but if want to, you should explicitly set layout manager to null for every panel. It's possible either via constructor invocation, or with `setLayout(null);` call.